# Error passing information between intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in android developing , currently i am working on android studio 1.5 with marshmallow 6.0 api 23, sdk tool 24.4.1. I am just testing passing extra information through explicit intent but every time after running i have got

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaca5a0c0
```

in my logcat. I think i did not code wrong . I have got the 2nd activity launched after tapping the button. so Intent switching is working but no information is passed there. So how could I solve this weird problem help will be appreciated

Here is my code :

```
package project.kalyan.intentdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main_intent_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{


   TextView tv;
   EditText ed;
   Button sendme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_intent_);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();





            }
        });

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstIntent);
        sendme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        sendme.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_intent_, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Main_intent_Activity.this,Activity_2.class);
            ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.intenttext);
            String passingtext=ed.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("Firstmessage:",passingtext);

            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }
}
```

i have tried getApplicationContext() in Intent parameter but no change

and my Activity 2 code is

```
package project.kalyan.intentdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView activetext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        activetext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity2text);
        Bundle information=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(information==null)
        {
            Log.d("State is :","Nothing is passed from main Activity");
            return;
        }
        String s=information.getString("Firstmessage");
        activetext.setText(s);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key is `"Firstmessage:"` not `"Firstmessage"`, you need to use the same key in the bundle returned from the intent in your 2nd activity

```
String s=information.getString("Firstmessage:");
```

Also please lookup your logcat because most probably this is not the throwable that causes the error

Comment: Thanks  that was silly mistake of mine  did not notice that . I have learnt it

Comment: @Kalyan no worries, but at least you learned that you should check other parts of your logcat as this is not the error anyways, because from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) it will return a `null`